# Angular $http.put packet not in correct format

Tags: angularjs

I'm kind of new to angular, and it's the first time I'm using $http.put.
My problem is when I send the packet, it won't include the data (json object), and the PUT is a header(?).

This is what my code looks like:

```
app.controller('StatusController',['$http', function($http) {
  this.updateComment = function (eventid, comment) {
    var requestData = {"event-id":eventid, "new-comment":comment};
    $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: "http://172.18.212.59/event",
      data: requestData,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
  }
}
```

So I used Fiddler to generate a PUT request to the server, and it worked. so I looked at the packets, trying to understand where the differences come from...
Here are the results:
[Packet generated by Angular - Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsy9T.jpg)
[Packet generated by the Fiddler Composer - Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxSw0.jpg)

Also I've tried using:

```
$http.put(url, requestData)
```

But that didn't work either... My GET requests work perfectly fine! And they look like the packet that does work...

Has anyone encountered this problem before?
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTIONS verb is used when doing cross domain requests. Basically you need to enable cross domain requests on your server side code. The GET request works cause it isn't protected by cross domain restrictions and Fiddler works cause cross domain requests comes into picture when making XHR requests from browser. If you look into the response to the OPTIONS request you will probably find something saying cross domain request not allowed.

Comment: I've asked our server-side developer, and he will look into it. But further more, is that normal that I don't see the JSON I send (the data) in the packet view? Either way, thanks for the quick reply!